# Save values from checklistbox to text file, then open the text file and repopulate the saved values back into the form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to save the selected items from the Type to a text file(checklistbox). 
I also am saving the main actors(treeview) to a text file 
This part works, and they are saving.
However when I try to open the text file to repopulate the data back into the form,
 I am getting the error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Below is my code for the save and open functions:

```
private void openDatabaseToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Open the file and upload the information 

    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    Stream s1 = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s1);
    saveDatabaseToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
    string infomovie = reader.ReadLine();
    string[] select = infomovie.Split('#');
    int nline = select.Length;
    txtTitle.Text = select[0];
    txtYear.Text = select[1];
    txtDir.Text = select[2];
    txtDur.Text = select[3];
    int nactors = Convert.ToInt32(select[4]);
    // put the number of actors in the file
    for (int i = 0; i < nactors; i++)
    {
       tvActor.Nodes.Add(select[4 + i]);
    }//end of for loop

    int genre = Convert.ToInt32(select[5]);
    // put the number of actors in the file
    for (int i = 0; i < genre; i++)
    {
        cBoxType.Items.Add(select[5 + i]);
    }//end of for loop

    reader.Close();
}

private void saveDatabaseToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //save data enter into form to text file

    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    Stream textOut = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textOut);

    //creates string called infomovie
    String infomovie = "";

    //prints parameters
    infomovie += txtTitle.Text + "#";
    infomovie += txtYear.Text + "#";
    infomovie += txtDir.Text + "#";
    infomovie += txtDur.Text + "#";

    //gets values from check list box 
    int genre = cBoxType.Items.Count;
    infomovie += genre.ToString() + "#";

    //gets values for tree view
    int nactors = tvActor.Nodes.Count;
    infomovie += nactors.ToString() + "#";

    for (int i = 0; i < nactors; i++)
    {
        //convert treeview to string
        infomovie += tvActor.Nodes[i].Text + ",";
    }

    //sep
    infomovie += "#";

    for (int i = 0; i < genre; i++)
    {
        if (cBoxType.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            //if statement to check which boxes are selected then converts to string
            infomovie += cBoxType.Items[i].ToString() + ",";
        }

    }

    //sep
    infomovie += "#";

    writer.WriteLine(infomovie);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please tell us which line brings up the error! Have you tried the debugger? (Upon the error simply choose 'break' and inspect the values..!

Comment: Which line you're receiving the error ?

Comment: tvActor.Nodes.Add(select[4 + i]);    << This is where the error is

Comment: I am seriously telling you, no one would ever understand select[0] is a movie title. I would advice you to create a DataModel serialize into xml and store it in the text file and read it back and deserialize the data.

Comment: Post the value of `infomovie`. Note the first call to `tvActor.Nodes.Add(select[4 + i])` will read the same value as `nactors`, and the second call will read the same value as `genre`; is that what you want?

Comment: @DourHighArch you're a good debugger. Do you accept break points as well ;P I seriously think the OP should learn how to debug the code instead.

Answer (score 0):

your `actor count stored at index 5` and `genre count is at 4` and `Actorlist at 6` and which is separated by `,` so you've to get element at index 6 and then split them by `,` and do loop over it and add it to `tvActor.Nodes`

```
 string[] actorlist= select[6].Split(',');
// Then Do loop here
```

Same goes for GenreList..